# Combining two types of conditions to replace strings with regular expressions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, replace, regular-expression

I have a string with commas at the beginning, at the end and sometimes two or more commas after each other: `,,`, as can see at the bottom. I tried to remove the commas in a way to have a comma separated string, using regular expressions.

- Deleting all commas at the beginning and the end of the string works fine:
  `regexp_replace (text, ('^,{1,}|,{1,}$'),'')`
- Replacing two or more commas with a single one inside the string works fine, too:
  `regexp_replace (text, (',{2,}'),',')`

However, how to combine these two cases? Like:

- If there is a comma at the beginning or the end: delete it
- If there are two or more commas, replace it with one.

Is this possible in one single regex_replace string? What works is combining them - so the solution I'm looking for should accomplish what the follwoing expression with two `regexp_replace` statements does, but using just a single `regexp_replace` function:

```
regexp_replace (
    regexp_replace (text, ('^,{1,}|,{1,}$'),''),
    (',{2,}'),','
)
```

```
old_text        new_text

,1              ->  1
1,              ->  1
1,,2            ->  1,2
,,,1,2,3,4,     ->  1,2,3,4
,1,2,3,4,5,,,   ->  1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,,,,,,6,7, ->  1,2,3,6,7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would you consider skipping the dark arts of regex for an array expression?

This should do the trick.

`array_to_string(array_filter(string_to_array(test,','),@element !=''),',')`

---

For a purely regex solution try this:

`regexp_replace(test,'^,*|,*$|(,)\\1+','\\1')`

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Edited with regex answer, hopefully that works. Now if you'll excuse me I hear Tony the Pony calling me...